# Angular js. Как получить результат из диалогового окна для единственной ячейки без повтора?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Есть рабочий код, который позволяет передавать данные из диалогового окна в таблицу. Для одного ряда все работает хорошо. Но если я хочу добавить несколько строк в таблицу, то я получаю результат сразу для нескольких столбцов. Как я могу получить результат для единственной ячейки без повтора, если я использую директиву angular ng-repeat?

**html**

```
        <table class="friends" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 10pt;" >
            <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>Name</th>
                 <th ng-repeat="tablerow in tableRows" style="padding: 0.5rem;">{{tablerow.name}}</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody >
            <tr ng-repeat="n in userName">
              <td>{{n.name}}</td>
              <td ng-repeat="t in tableRows" class="category-{{t.favoriteColor}} table-height">
                    <i class="material-icons dark md-18" ng-click="open($index, $event, it)">mode_edit</i> 

                    {{t.placeholder1}}
                    <br><hr>
                    {{t.placeholder2}}

                </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

**js**

```
        $scope.tableRows = [
            { name: 'AAA', 'placeholder1': null, 'placeholder2': null, favoriteColor: null },
            { name: 'BBB', 'placeholder1': null, 'placeholder2': null, favoriteColor: null },
            { name: 'CCC', 'placeholder1': null, 'placeholder2': null, favoriteColor: null },
            { name: 'DDD', 'placeholder1': null, 'placeholder2': null, favoriteColor: null },
            { name: 'EEE', 'placeholder1': null, 'placeholder2': null, favoriteColor: null },
            { name: 'FFF', 'placeholder1': null, 'placeholder2': null, favoriteColor: null }
        ];
```

Полный код и пример на [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jCI0lFFgwX0jZXIHZY88?p=preview)

Comment: Так у Вас нигде не хранится результат для единственной ячейки, для всех юзеров отрисовывается один и тот же `tableRows`. Вам для каждого юзера надо иметь свой собственный массив `tableRows` (хотя по смыслу логичнее было бы его назвать `tableColumns`)

Comment: Результат планирую передавать и сохранять в базе данных на сервере. Хорошо, попробую переписать массив для каждого юзера.

Comment: Навскидку - https://plnkr.co/edit/gcIME9F8Z9LE066C2vww?p=preview (вторую таблицу не трогал)

Comment: Да, на выходе должно получаться так, только данные еще нужно передавать и во вторую таблицу.

Comment: Обновил. Там есть непонятная мне проблема с классом `table-hover`, если он указан для второй таблицы, то в обоих таблицах всё перестает отображаться. Поэтому убрал, разбираться со стилями - это не мой конёк :)

Comment: Спасибо за решение! Буду разбираться.